# unorderable types: int() > list()

Tags: python

after executing this code:

```
def arrayChange(inputArray):
    inputArray.append([10**6])
    sum = 0

    for i in range(len(inputArray)):
        while inputArray[i] > inputArray[i+1]:
            inputArray[i+1] += 1
            sum += 1

    return sum
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  file.py3 on line ?, in getUserOutputs
    userOutput = _runickrl(testInputs[i])
  file.py3 on line ?, in _runickrl
    return arrayChange(*_fArgs_sxkojsugpnwr)
  file.py3 on line 6, in arrayChange
    while inputArray[i] > inputArray[i+1]:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > list()
```

Do anyone know why is this happening? I tried everything what I found.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with this function? `append([10**6])` appends a list to a list. That's why the error `unorderable types: int() > list()`.

Comment: Check your comparison type by : type(variable name) . for inserting 10 elements to list you can do a=[0]*10 ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `inputArray.append([10**6])` you are actually appending a list to the `inputArray` list.

You assume every element of `inputArray` to be integer, but when you do `while inputArray[i] > inputArray[i+1]` with `i=0`, the first element is a list, the next element is an integer, so it gives you the error "unorderable types: int() > list()".

If you mean to append just one element, what you need to do is `inputArray.append(10**6)`.

If you were looking to append many items at once, what you are looking for is extend: `inputArray.extend([1, 2, 3])`.